# Change content of some JSON file using powershell pipeline

Tags: powershell

I want to change content of JSON file from a bat file. I thought doing that by calling powershell and use a single-line pipeline command.

Here I am so far:

```
Get-Content test.json -raw | ConvertFrom-Json | Set-ItemProperty -Name "ServiceAccess.Host" -Value "localhost:5000" |  ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content test.json
```

Here is my JSON file:

```
{
    "ServiceAccess":  
    {
        "Host":  "localhost:3000"
    }
}
```

It does not work:

> Set-ItemProperty : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does
>   not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
>   At line:1 char:49
>   + ... From-Json | Set-ItemProperty -Name "ServiceAccess.Host" -Value "local ...
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (@{ServiceAccess=}:PSObject) [Set-ItemProperty], ParameterBindingExcept
>      ion
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetItemPropertyCommand

What is the proper way to change a JSON object in the powershell pipeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you must do it all in a single pipeline (spread across multiple lines for readability):

```
Get-Content test.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json |
  ForEach-Object { $_.ServiceAccess.Host = 'localhost:5000'; $_ } |
    ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content test.json
```

Note that using `-Raw` to read the entire input file at once makes it possible to write back to the same file in the same pipeline (without `-Raw`, you'd have to enclose the `Get-Content` call in `(...)` to force reading of its lines all at once).

In the `ForEach-Object` block, the input object is first modified (`$_.ServiceAccess.Host = 'localhost:5000'`), and then (`;`) passed through (`$_`) to `ConvertTo-Json` for reconversion to JSON, which `Set-Content` then writes back to the input file.

---

As for **what you tried**:

`*-Item*` cmdlets such as `Set-ItemProperty` aren't designed for general in-memory object manipulation.

Instead, an *item* is a specific type of object that a [PowerShell provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_providers) exposes, such as a file or folder in the case of the filesystem provider, or a registry key in the case of the registry provider.

Answer (score 0):

```
$Json = Get-Content test.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$Json.ServiceAccess.Host = 'localhost:5000'
$Json | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content test.json
```

If you bang on it for awhile you could probably get this into a single line of code, but you may run into file locking issues when `Get-Content` and `Set-Content` are operating on the same file in the same pipeline.

Be aware that PowerShell's JSON support is a little quirky. This is partially due to the fact that it uses the .Net dialect of JSON, which isn't always identical to the JSON that other systems use. Second, JSON support is a relatively recent addition, so Windows PowerShell (v5.1 and below) is more quirky than PowerShell Core (v6+). If your outermost JSON element is an unnamed array, for example, PowerShell will tend to drop the square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$json = get-content test.json | ConvertFrom-Json           
$json | % { $_.ServiceAccess.Host = "localhost:5000" }     
$json | ConvertTo-Json | out-file test1.json
```